# how can I dynamically create WCF endpoints vs a static endpoint defined in the config file?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

What I currently have is is a multi-party, multi-chat app; P2P at that, which uses the older .NET v2.0 method. Intranet only.

What I'm after is how to dynamically create WCF endpoints versus a static endpoint defined in the config file;  I can do the rest. I'll be using a generic message vs. static (predefined), so this allows for dynamic message passing.  I'll use the HTTP transport in WCF to send and receive “plain old XML” (POX) messages; that is, messages that consist solely of XML payloads without any enclosing SOAP envelope.

OR should I just assume that the same base port is all that is needed for every workstation and merely use that as the sole port, and that there's no network clash conflict (e.g. 2 guest workstations simultaneously communicating with the same host workstation)?

I'd like to move it to WCF, but the endpoint thing has got me; e.g. can't seem to figure it out.

History:
My current chat app uses the older .NET v2.0 method.  I have about 50 workstations and each is assigned a static port, e.g. 50100, 50200, 50300, etc.  This allows for up to 99 ports in the range of 50100 ~ 50199; port 50100 is the 'base' port, and ports 50101 ~ 50199 are 'host' ports which allows up to 99 'host' chat sessions simultaneously. The workstation can host several chat sessions on, say, ports 50101 thru 50105.  They can also 'join' (be a guest) on chats within the port range of the other workstations.

Each workstation is 'listening' on their base port, e.g. 50100.  When a chat request comes in on their base port, the requesting "server" provides the dynamically created port to 'join' the chat request as a guest.  In this example, workstation A (base port 50100) gets an invite from workstation B to join on port 50235 (50200 is Workstation B's 'base' port for incoming chat requests).
BTW: I use a web service to track when users are online or not.  The chat app registers/unregisters with the web service when opening/quitting.

Current WFC model
With WCF, I don't see how this model above can be 'ported' (no pun intended) into the WCF model.  The config file shows a single port for all workstations.  Can multiple chats occur on the same port, both as host and guest?  I would think not.

The short of it being, how could I dynamically create endpoints purely in C# code, no static config file endpoint, or can I? I can't seem to find any examples.

That is, the base workstation port (endpoint) will 'listen' for chat requests; it will create an endpoint to send a chat request to another workstation's base port (endpoint), and will create an endpoint when invited to a chat.

Thx,

GaryN

Answer (score 2):

You can define a service endpoint in code instead of in the configuration file, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731080.aspx